# Javascript: Record Audio from a HTML5 audio element playing LiveStream (e.g. Internet Radio)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, ionic-framework

I want to record audio from a html5 audio element playing radio live stream. I found libraries which can record from microphone or camera but none i was looking for.

Can anybody please help me if i could use javascript to record and save the output of a html audio node on the device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little detail into what you were looking for and what you have already discarded would help

Comment: @Prateek, I was looking at Recorderjs and https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html.                  I tried to tweek them to record output of audio src instead but no luck.